# flattening product category hierarchy

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have read so much on flattening parent child hierarchies but finding it hard to implement it. I have a product table where I have ChildCategoryDesc and ParentCategoryDesc. There are 4 levels of hierarchies in some cases and I want to see the highest hierarchy level in the ParentCategoryDesc. See below for code:

Initial code:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID
    ,cat.categoryDesc AS 'ChildCategoryDesc'
    ,ISNULL(cat2.categoryDesc,cat.categoryDesc) AS 'ParentCategoryDesc'
FROM dbo.product p
INNER JOIN dbo.category cat ON cat.categoryID = p.categoryID
LEFT JOIN  dbo.category cat2 ON cat.parentCategoryID = cat2.CategoryID
```

What I tried to deal with the hierarchy issue:

```
--Listing 2: Static Query Baased on Joins
WITH C AS
(
  SELECT
    A.categoryID
   ,A.categoryID AS A_catid
   ,B.categoryID AS B_catid
   ,C.categoryID AS C_catid
   ,D.categoryID AS D_catid
   ,( SELECT COUNT(A.categoryID)
    FROM (VALUES(A.categoryID),(B.categoryID),(C.categoryID),(D.categoryID)) AS D(categoryID) ) AS lvl
  FROM dbo.category AS A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.category AS B
    ON A.categoryID = B.categoryID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.category AS C
    ON B.categoryID = C.categoryID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.category AS D
    ON C.categoryID = D.categoryID

  GROUP BY A.categoryID,B.categoryID,C.categoryID,D.categoryID
  )
SELECT categoryID, lvl,
  CASE 1
    WHEN lvl     THEN A_catid
    WHEN lvl - 1 THEN B_catid
    WHEN lvl - 2 THEN C_catid
    WHEN lvl - 3 THEN D_catid
  END AS level1,
  CASE 2
    WHEN lvl     THEN A_catid
    WHEN lvl - 1 THEN B_catid
    WHEN lvl - 2 THEN C_catid
  END AS level2,
  CASE 3
    WHEN lvl     THEN A_catid
    WHEN lvl - 1 THEN B_catid
  END AS level3,
  CASE 4
    WHEN lvl     THEN A_catid
  END AS level4
FROM C
```

**EDIT:**

With my initial code the data looks like this:

[image]
[image]

All the products in category edit eventually end up in dresses but with my current code it isnt doing that. Its only going one level up with regards to parentCategoryID.

**Check my initial code for change**

**NEW EDIT**

I just wrote the following code and it seems to be working, can someone just tell me whether this will have high performance implications or its ok to go with it.

```
SELECT distinct productDesc
    ,cat.categoryID
    ,cat.categoryDesc
    ,cat.categoryDesc AS 'ChildCategoryDesc'
    ,CASE
        WHEN cat4.categoryDesc IS NOT NULL
        THEN cat4.categoryDesc

        WHEN cat3.categorydesc IS NOT NULL
        THEN cat3.categoryDesc

        WHEN cat2.categoryDesc IS NOT NULL
        THEN cat2.categoryDesc

        ELSE cat.categoryDesc
    END AS 'ParentCategoryDesc'
    ,cat.[ParentCategoryID]
    ,cat.[ParentCategoryTypeID]
FROM scv_build.dbo.product p                   
INNER JOIN scv_build.dbo.category cat ON cat.categoryID = p.categoryID   
LEFT JOIN dbo.category cat2 ON cat.parentCategoryID = cat2.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN dbo.category cat3 ON cat2.parentCategoryID = cat3.categoryID
LEFT JOIN dbo.category cat4 ON cat3.parentCategoryID = cat4.categoryID
```

Comment: So even if your category is in the forth level, you want ParentCategoryDesc to reflect the first level?

Comment: How do you determine which category is the parent? I was expecting you to have a "ParentID" column or something along those lines

Comment: So lets assume we have a product named `Cadbury(Milkshake)` the hierarchy would be something like `Cadbury --> Powder -->Dairy --> Hot Drinks`. With my initial code the Powder would be made the parent category, but i want it to be Hot Drinks.

Comment: @Jonny I dont know anything about this in sql hence why i was asking. The code I tried, I found somewhere on internet. Didnt work for me though thats why i'm here

Comment: please show what your table looks like

Comment: @Jonny check edits above

Comment: You have a table named Category. Which columns do you have in that table?

Comment: `[categoryID],[categoryCode],[categoryDesc],[categoryCreateDate],[categoryTypeID],[parentCategoryID],[parentCategoryTypeID]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115983/discussion-between-faiz-and-jonny).

Comment: @Jonny there must be a way to add another column in my category table for each category to cantain its top hierarchical level category?